# Apache POI HWPFDocument help insert a hyperlink

Tags: java, apache-poi, cpu-word, .doc

Is it possible in CharacterRun how to set that this is a hyperlink? Or is there some other way? Help me please.

Comment: Use XWPF / docx instead? Much easier to implement file format, so much better support in Apache POI

Comment: @Gagravarr With XWPF / docx there are no problems, the task is simply to work with two formats.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.